# Eclipse building Android app: How can I create two versions/editions at compile-time?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm writing an Android application and would like to create two versions based on the same code -- a free and a premium version.  I have one codebase for both versions with various run-time checks to enable or disable certain features, e.g.

```
public class MyAppContext extends Application
{
    public static final boolean isPremium = true;
}

// later, in another file....
if (!MyAppContext.isPremium) {
   CoolFeatures.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I'm using the latest dev tools (Eclipse Indigo with Google's ADT 16).  Right now I follow a fairly cumbersome process of setting isPremium to true in my source file, exporting the app into an APK, then setting it to false and exporting it a second time into a different APK.  This is both annoying and error-prone.

Is there a way to automate this process?  That is,

1) Create two different build configurations so that when I export my app, two APK files are generated.

2) Have the build configuration affect the code at compile-time -- for example, setting a static boolean to true or false.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the [Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects).

Answer (score 4):

Take your project and change it into a library project. Then create two applications (free, premium) and import the library. Then you can inherit the `MyAppContext` object and change the `isPremium` member as needed, maybe by using an additional `setPremium()` functions.

Watch out, in the manifest XML you have to use the package name of the library project for each activity, service, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you automate the build with ant. You can use the same target with different parameter (say path to properties file you will read in the java code). You will need to make sure the two apks will be named differently of course, however this is the approach most continuous build tools do it for different environments, which is essentially the same.

Comment: you will also need to have a different package name in the APK. I'm not familar with ant scripts... is that possible as well?

Comment: You mean that is the case in which we want both the premium and the free version being installed on the same device? However, this makes no sense to me - why do you need to have the code in both applications? This will be true both with the Library project idea and ant build.

Comment: I have already an existing app (free/paid) using the library project approach (like I've stated in my answer) and I was just wondering if an ant script would be an alternative solution for another future project. Different package names for me are a clean way to difference both app versions, especially when testing both on my devices.

Comment: I have seen the free/paid functionality implemented several times. However the paid part is always smaller - it just holds a key to unlock the additional functions of the free app. I think the main reason for that is otherwise the user gets twice the same functionality in two different applications, which requires twice as much storage. Also the synchronization of the two versions of the two apps will be very difficult. Why in fact do you need the free app if the paid one is installed in your case?

Comment: On the end user's phone of course only one of them is supposed to be installed, though when migrating from free to paid it's possible that both are installed for a while. I didn't want to use the "Pro app is only a key" approach because then the user has always deal with two APKs. For example after a factory reset only paid applications are restored automatically (at least on my phone)... so in this case only the key is restored, without the APK containing the functionality!? Not very cool. As for synchronizing apps this isn't too bad since all common code is in the library project.